# can't assign value to "const char * const *my_array" in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, constants

Bellow is my C code:

```
const char *l = "some text";
const char * const *m = {l};
```

When I try to compile that code, I get this warning:

> warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Can anybody explain me why that warning and how should I initialize the second variable (`m`)?

Comment: Why are you using { }?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are not using the `const` keyword in the right way. `const` applies to the first left token it meets or, if there is not, to the first right token.

So, in your case :

```
const char * const *m;
```

The first `const` applies to `char`, just like for `l`. The second one applies to your first `*`, which means that m is a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant content ("some text"). Since you had not written

```
const char * const l;
```

There is a conflict with the const-ness of your two pointers hence the warning.

I think what you want is to guarantee that the address stored in `l` won't be altered by the program. If it is that so, then you must change the declaration of `l` to this one :

```
const char * const l = "some text";
```

Comment: can you provide the documentation for: *`const` applies to the first left token it meets or, if there is not, to the first right token.* ? Thanks for the right answer!

Comment: in your case m is a pointer to a const pointer to a char constant(just as @Rerito said). according to clockwise spiral rule which you can find right here: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: @artaxerxe You can check Wikipedia's page about const-correctness : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness. It also can be inferred from the examples you will find on http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html
I just expressed the _rule_ in an easier to remember fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
const char* m[] = {l};
```

I think that should work.

I imagine you actually intend `m` to be more than one element long, otherwise you would not do something so convoluted, right?

Comment: because I need a that type: `const char * const *`